# Adding 3rd dimension to 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm having a 2D array of dummy variables (0 and 1) with the shape of (4432, 35) -> 4432 videos including 35 different customers. Since the videos contain of 1800 frames I want to add a third dimension to this array with 1800 time steps (frames) so that it gets the shape (4432, 35, 1800). So I want Python to multiplicate the zeros and ones in the 2nd dimension 1800 times into the 3rd dimension.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with `multiplicate the zeros and ones`?

Comment: So it's basically that I want to copy the 2D array 1800 times and fuse them together into a 3D array.

Comment: Then you're talking about the first axis iiuc, are you sure you don't want `(1800, 4432, 35)`?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal toy example with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

with an array called array with any 2D shape:

```
array = [[[j for k in range(1800)] for j in i] for i in array]
```

This will create a 3rd dimension with 1800 duplicates of the values in the second dimension.

It also seems to make more sense to have a shape (4432, 1800, 35): (video, frame, customers in frame):

```
array = [[i for k in range(1800)] for i in array]
```